# Why is circle getting appended outside the body? D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

Trying to make a scatter plot but the circles are getting appended outside the SVG.

```
var line_fatality = svg
    .append('g')
    .classed('fatality',true)
    .data(check[0].values)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr('cx', (function (d, i) {
        return x(d.date)
    }))
    .attr('cy', (function (d, i) { return y(d.fatality) }))
    .attr("r", 1.5)
    .style("fill", "#69b3a2")
```

[Circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KET2h.png)
[SVG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NahHu.png)

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it. For anyone wondering why it doesn't work then try adding selectAll in your code.

```
var line_fatality = svg
        .selectAll("dot")
        .append('g')
        .classed('fatality',true)
        .data(check[0].values)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr('cx', (function (d, i) {
            return x(d.date)
        }))
        .attr('cy', (function (d, i) { return y(d.fatality) }))
        .attr("r", 1.5)
        .style("fill", "#69b3a2")
```

[Updated SVG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aezx8.png)